# table of contents in dynamic document created with dyndoc

Tags: java, php, html, markdown, stata

I have a question with regards to dynamic documents written with Stata 15. I am using the `dyndoc` command, you can see how it works with examples [here](https://www.stata.com/new-in-stata/markdown/).

Since in some of my reports there is plenty of content, I would like to include a table of content at the beginning of each file. I am not sure, but it seems to me that there is no support for anything similar with `dyndoc`. However, the command structure allows embedding html snippets with `dd_include`, including a reference to a `css` style sheet (see [here](https://www.stata.com/manuals/pdyndoc.pdf)). Therefore, I thought I could include a java or php script in a `header.txt` (see the previous link) and go down that path.

In the markdown language every title generated with a series of `###` becomes an `<h>` element in the `html` after the `dyndoc` conversion. Therefore, I thought I need a script which identifies these `<h>` elements and creates the table. I have tried several options with java from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/187619/is-there-a-javascript-solution-to-generating-a-table-of-contents-for-a-page/41085566#41085566) and with php from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4912275/automatically-generate-nested-table-of-contents-based-on-heading-tags). However, none of this works, and I am not even sure I am on the right path.

Is there anyone with some more experience with similar issues? I'd appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have managed to do it, following the answer by Hasse Björk at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/187619/is-there-a-javascript-solution-to-generating-a-table-of-contents-for-a-page/41085566#41085566).

As he describes, I included the code snippet for the java script he provides in the header.txt (see above), wrapped in `<script type="text/javascript">` and the corresponding `</script>`. Then, in the actual markdown file which `dyndoc` parses I included the following line, at the beginning of the file: `<nav id="toc"><strong><font size="6">Content of this section</font></strong></nav>` You can format it as you wanted, but I avoided the `<h>` tag in order not to list the content table in the content table. I also added the formatting options suggested in the original answer to the style sheet.